# event.preventDefault() not working in validation

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I have a page where users can comment under posts. The post and comments are loaded using ajax. I am trying to validate the comment form using the below code.

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('submit', event => {
                if (event.target.matches('.needs-validation')) {
                    if (event.target.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        event.target.classList.add('was-validated');
                }
            }, false);
```

The comment form is submitted using ajax.

```
$('body').on('submit', '.cmnt-frm', function(e) {
```

Now the form is getting validated and an error message is showing, but the form is getting submitted using ajax. `event.preventDefault()` is not working.
The below code works, but only for the initial page load. On submitting a new post the post list gets updated using ajax, in that case this doesn't work

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                // Loop over them and prevent submission
                var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                        form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                });

            }, false);
```

What is wrong with the code. Please help.

Comment: PreventDefault does NOTHING to prevent your other event listeners from running.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/

Comment: Seems odd you would not handle the submission in one place.

Comment: @epascarello Question updated

Comment: @epascarello I want to use the default browser validation. I got the code from bootstrap website. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation

Comment: @Akhilesh yes, but you can check it from the jQuery code, nothing says you have to use that other function. `$('body').on('submit', '.cmnt-frm', function(e) { if (!this.checkValidity()) { event.preventDefault(); return; } /* other code */ })`

Answer (score -1):

event.target.className.matches('needs-validation') .....